# Angular 5 with Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Would like opinions on the best method to change the links in a sidenav based on authentication. App structure currently is as follows

`<app-navbar></app-navbar>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <page>Pages will show here</page>`

I've considered creating a `service` and using events to pass the routes/links to the sidenav, but would like to get some opinions on the angular way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first instinct is, in my opinion, the correct one. I use a service to communicate between components and the sidenav in all of my Angular apps.

From the official angular tutorial:

> Services are a great way to share information among classes that don't know each other.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Great! I thought so too.  I'm trying to get my brain thinking like Angular, coming from react.  Liking Angular thus far.